# Open-source software to automatically generate simple flow chart

Tags: open-source, automation, programming, charts, flowchart

I want to programmatically create small, really simple flow charts like the one below:

[image: flowchart]

Source: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:LampFlowchart.svg

What is a good open-source software choice to do this?

Answer (score 3):

For simple graphs I could recommend [d2lang](https://d2lang.com/tour/intro/)

```
#file: d2-example-lamp-bulb.d2
Lamp doen't work: Problem {
  Lamp plugged in? -> Bulb burned out?:yes
  Bulb burned out? -> Replace bulb:yes
}
```

call it with the shell command:
`~/apps/d2/bin/d2 -w d2-example-lamp-bulb.d2 d2-example-lamp-bulb.svg`

This generates

[image]

---

From 2022:
The classic software for doing this is [Graphviz](https://graphviz.org/)  and its "dot" language.

There are several language bindings available, for many programming languages, actually. Many apps are built on top of graphviz, see [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphviz).

There is *[a very comprehensive repository "Awesome Graphviz"](https://github.com/CodeFreezr/awesome-graphviz)*  with lots of graphviz related links.

Recently I came across [DiagrammeR](https://rich-iannone.github.io/DiagrammeR/), but this requires substantial web development skills and full commitment to the modern R ecosystem (R + RStudio + htmlwidgets + JavaScript + d3.js + viz.js + mermaid.js).

But see 2-minute showcasing video on their homepage. It shows almost pure graphviz code (wrapped in a single R function). From simple graph to more complex graph, with animations and "hot reloading".

[Previous related Qs](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=graphviz%20is%3AQ) about Graphviz and Alternatives

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://app.diagrams.net/ for free in your browser. It is easy to use!

Click on `Create New Diagram` and it lets you select from various flowchart templates:

[image: flowchart models at diagrams.net]